# Are there any texts/translations of the 4 main Egyptian creation myths?

Tags: ancient-history, ancient-egypt, bible, archaeology, historical-research

According to wikipedia there are 4 main [Egyptian Creation Myths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Egyptian_creation_myths). These appear to be:

- Ogdoad creaton myth of Hermopolis
- Creation myth of Atum from Heliopolis
- Creation myth of Ptah from Memphis
- Creation myth of Amun from Thebes

I am planning to answer a [question over at the Biblical Hermeneutics Q&A site](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/1252/what-are-the-similarities-and-differences-between-the-genesis-creation-account-a), and while I have a general overview of these myths I can't seem to find the name of a definitive, Canonical source for these myths. Does such a thing even exist? If not, why? Is this information collected over a number of references and stories or from artwork for example?

In contrast, the Babylonian creation myths sources seem to be very easy to locate and I am wondering why there is a disparity.

Comment: I'm not sure if your question is on-topic on this site (http://meta.history.stackexchange.com/q/123/230), but Stack Exchange has a site [about mythology](http://mythology.stackexchange.com/) that you should take a look at.

Comment: Hmm. I don't know either. I'm really just looking to find out if there is a specific source text for each of the 4 above and if not, why.

Comment: As far as I understand the primary sources for these myths are: The Book of the Dead; the Shabaka stone; the Bremner-Rhind papyrus; and the Coffin Texts. But I can't find a good online source.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it a request for sources.

Comment: I think this verges on a request for canonical sources, which seems to be within scope.  I admit the possibility of diversity of opinion, but I would tend to grant the benefit of the doubt.

Comment: I am either looking for Canonical sources or an explanation for why they do not exist.

Comment: @user4419802 Expand that into an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an incomplete answer so far. Any additions and suggestions are welcome.

- **Heliopolis myth** is based upon the excerpt from [The Bremner-Rhind Papyrus](http://www.britishmuseum.org/research/collection_online/collection_object_details.aspx?objectId=113956&partId=1) known as *The Book of Knowing of the Creations of Ra*. English translation available [online](http://www.reshafim.org.il/ad/egypt/texts/history_of_creation.htm).
- **Memphis myth** is based upon [The Shabaka Stone](http://www.britishmuseum.org/explore/highlights/highlight_objects/aes/t/the_shabako_stone.aspx). English translation available [online](http://www.reshafim.org.il/ad/egypt/texts/shabaka_stone.htm).
- **Hermopolis myth** is compiled from the scattered fragments of [The Book of the Dead](http://www.sacred-texts.com/egy/ebod/index.htm) and [The Coffin Texts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffin_Texts).
- **Thebes myth** is known by some late compilative papyrus of times of the Ptolemaic dynasty which title I was unable to find out.